What is the movie where planes fall from the sky?
There is a film made in 2012/13 and in the trailer the guy is on a phone and planes start falling from the sky and cars stop working, then mobiles; it's like everything in the world stops working.

It's not a movie, it's the NBC television series Revolution.  A trailer like the one you remember is on YouTube.

thats the one, Thank you very much its been bugging me for hours you have now put my mind at rest.
